# Rigging a humanoid problem: Parenting with automatic weights twists legs around

Tags: rigging

This is what my humanoid mesh looks like:

[image: Look of the mesh before parenting]

As you can see, after parenting the mesh with the armature, the legs twist around while other parts of the body look correct. Is this related to the roll of the lower leg bone? Recalculating the rolls yields different, but incorrect results.

[image: Look of the mesh after parenting it with the armature]

There are pole targets in front of the lower leg bones, I have adjusted the pole angle visible in screenshot 3 to get a correct a bending of the knee, but the mesh is still deformed.

[image: Pole target settings]

Actually, I did get the mesh to look correct by correcting the pole angles of the lower leg bones, but then the bending of the knee is incorrect

[image: Correct mesh incorrect bend]

Could somebody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried manually adjusting the roll of the leg bones?

Comment: I tried, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right mode, under the right circumstances... Before parenting? After? Changing the roll in edit mode after parenting doesn't seem to change anything in pose mode... Maybe it has something to do with 'rest pose'. I'll read more into that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

**BEFORE** applying the armature to the mesh, I moved the leg bones so they wouldn't be completely straight and would have a slight bend in the direction the knee should move after being applied. After that, it was a matter of adjusting the pole angles.

Comment: If this worked for you, you can accept your own answer. Don't worry, you won't look bad, because you won't get any reputation from accepting :) This might help other people with the same problem.

Comment: @R.M thanks for letting me know! still new to this amazing network

Answer (score 0):

When using Automatic weights, I have experience warping due to bad weight distribution. It was beneficial for me to use Weight Paint Mode (You enter Weight Paint mode from the Mode Menu (Ctrl-Tab)). It could be that another part of your armature is controlling something it shouldn't.